# Is logging available for Zappa Lambda hosted Django sites?

Tags: django, python-zappa

I'm looking at moving a personal site from Heroku to Lambda using Zappa. Will persistent logs be available once I've deployed using Zappa? I've seen the Zappa tailing logs command but I'm talking about persistent logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda functions [by default log](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html) to [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch), and the Zappa `tail` command merely reads from that CloudWatch stream. Yes, your logs will be persistent (as persistent as you [configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html#SettingLogRetention) them to be).

Comment: I have a flask application and i want to deploy that on aws environment using zappa. so, do i need to use `zappa tail dev` and `zappa package dev` command right?

Comment: i want to see logging messages present in my flask application

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in their [github:](https://github.com/zappa/Zappa#tailing-logs)
`By default, this will show all log items. In addition to HTTP and other events, anything printed to stdout or stderr will be shown in the logs.`

and I can personally say `print`'s will be logged.